# PCI Express "host' solution within a FPGA device

Tags: express, fpga, host, pci

I am working on a project as a trainee with the goal to develop a PCI Express "host" solution on an Intel Arria FPGA 10.

The purpose of the project is to obtain a "host" "rootport" architecture capable of providing data exchanges with other devices via the PCI Express bus.

At first, I am focused on the possibility of using the hardware PCI Express Hard-IP of the FPGA and the embedded hard processor system. The PCI Express system is used for communication on the bus and the hard processor block for initialization and management.

Does this idea seem feasible? PCI Express on FPGA (on memory chip, DMA, MSI, BARs etc ...) and my lack of experience of the subject does not help me much.

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: My answer to this question is "yes." That might not be very helpful, which is why @KasiaGogolek suggests improving the question. Also, make use of the documentation, examples, and reference designs from the FPGA vendor.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly feasible to develop a PCI Express solution on an FPGA. It may not be feasible for you to develop such a system, in a reasonable amount of time, by yourself, and with only the skills of a trainee.

I can offer some weak encouragement to try. Very hard problems are just not necessarily the best way to start learning.

If you are part of a larger project team then I would recommend asking for a tiny piece of the problem to work on. For example, learn how the FPGA's hardened PCI express controller BAR's are configured within the IP configuration tool.

Good luck.